# Simplify object on JSON serialisation

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

Given the following 2 classes (edited for brevity), I am generating a list of questions. Each question is assigned a 'UserAccount'.

I then want to serialise the list of questions, but for each UserAccount, I only want to write the 'Id' property (exclude any other properties on the UserAccount object).

I think I need a custom converter to perform this, but am unsure how to go about intercepting any occurrence of the UserAccount property, and only serialise the Id property on it.

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Ask { get; set; }
    public UserAccount CreatedBy { get; set; }
}

public class UserAccount
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

This is what the resulting JSON would ideally look like:

```
[
   {
      "Id":1,
      "Ask":"Question 1",
      "CreatedBy":{
         "Id":1
      }
   },
   {
      "Id":2,
      "Ask":"Question 2",
      "CreatedBy":{
         "Id":1
      }
   },
   {
      "Id":3,
      "Ask":"Question 3",
      "CreatedBy":{
         "Id":1
      }
   }
]
```

I don't want to use Ignore attributes against the UserAccount class, as in some other business cases, I might want all of the attributes serialised. In fact, I don't want to have to modify either the Question or UserAccount class.

Comment: that means you want to serialize only `id` property in `Question` class, right?

Comment: Is this part of an API? In other words, what are you doing with the serialized data?

Comment: @er-sho I want to serialise all of the properties on Question, but when serialising each occurrence of UserAccount on Question, I only want the Id property output in the JSON under UserAccount.

Comment: @marcusstarnes, show your code for serialization.

Comment: _"I don't want to use Ignore attributes against the UserAccount class,"_ Would an ignore on the property in `Question` be OK?

Comment: @Fildor No, lets say that I cannot make any modifications to either the Question or the UserAccount classes.

Comment: @marcusstarnes Please check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You want to ignore the other properties **conditionally**. To achieve this, using NewtonJson you can simply add a method to your class next to the properties which has the following signiture (**bool ShouldSerialize[PropertyName]**), see the [official documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/conditionalproperties.htm) for more details.

So your code will look like this

```
public class UserAccount
{
    // This will be serialized
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // This may (or may not) be be serialized depending on your condition
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // This also may (or may not) be be serialized depending on your condition
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeName()
    {
        if(someCondition)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool ShouldSerializeEmail()
    {
        if(someCondition)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to edit your original classes, you may for example wrap them inside another class (or inherit from them), and use the derrived class. So you just inherit the properties and add the methods to the derrived class. This could be one possible solution (I am not sure if you might get a better solution).

Comment: @Fildor, I added a small text update at the end of the answer

Answer (score 0):

if you are using NewtonSoft in order to do that you have to add "JsonIgnore" attribute to the prop(or "DataContract" to the class and "DataMember" to the prop) or implement IContractResolver

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReducingSerializedJSONSize.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [custom JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for your requirement and within the 'WriteJson' method, you can try the following implementation:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    JToken t = JToken.FromObject(value);

    if (t.Type != JTokenType.Object)
    {
        t.WriteTo(writer);
    }
    else
    {
        JObject o = (JObject)t;
        var property = o.Properties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "CreatedBy");
        if(property != null)
        {
            o.Remove(property.Name);
            var newObj = new JObject();
            newObj.Add(new JProperty("Id",((JObject)property.Value).Properties().First(p => p.Name == "Id").Value));
            var newProperty = new JProperty(property.Name, newObj);
            o.Add(newProperty);
            o.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

And the serialization code would be like this:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(questions,  // your list of 'Question'
                                       Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, 
                                       new MyCustomJsonConverter(typeof(Question)));
```